# Create Gradle Tasks that executes other gradle task with parameters

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I use this gradle command to execute my UI-tests:
`./gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest -PUiTest`

I want to define a custom gradle task that executes my UI-tests, so I could this:

```
task runUiTests() {
    dependsOn("connectedDebugAndroidTest")
}
```

How can I pass the parameter `-PUiTest` in my custom gradle task to the `connectedDebugAndroidTest` task?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to this perhaps?