# How to wrap an existing Gradle task with parameters into a custom task?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am trying to create a custom Gradle task which invokes an existing Gradle task with parameters which are specific to my project. Here is how I invoke the task from the command line:

```
./gradlew downloadJson \
    -Pendpoint=http://example.com/foo \
    -Pdestination=src/main/com/example/foo.json
```

I would like to create a `downloadFoo` task which I can invoke without specifying the parameters explicitely.

```
tasks.register("downloadFoo" /* type needed? */) {
    // What goes here?
}
```

## Related

- [Create Gradle Tasks that executes other gradle task with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284240/create-gradle-tasks-that-executes-other-gradle-task-with-parameters)
- [How to pass Custom gradle Task as parameter to another Custom gradle Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55115415/how-to-pass-custom-gradle-task-as-parameter-to-another-custom-gradle-task)

Comment: Do you have access to the `downloadJson` task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real concept of tasks *wrapping* other tasks in Gradle...

What you can do in this situation is to just create a new task of type `ApolloDownloadSchemaTask`, and then set the properties:

```
import com.apollographql.apollo.gradle.internal.ApolloDownloadSchemaTask

tasks.register("downloadFoo", ApolloDownloadSchemaTask) { task ->
    description("Downloads foo.")
    group("Apollo")
    task.schemaFilePath.set("src/main/com/example/foo.json")
    task.endpointUrl.set("http://example.com/foo")
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the `downloadJson` task. It is provided by a third party Gradle plugin. I want to add a custom wrapper task which set the parameters specific to my use case.

Comment: Which plugin? Is it publicly available?

Comment: I want to wrap the [`downloadApolloSchema` task](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android#downloading-a-schemajson-file) of the [Apollo Gradle plugin](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android).

Comment: Updated answer...  You'll have to watch [the task class](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/blob/master/apollo-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/com/apollographql/apollo/gradle/internal/ApolloDownloadSchemaTask.kt) for changes as it's marked `internal`, so may change, but that should work for `1.3.1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this form:

```
tasks.register("downloadBackendSchema", com.apollographql.apollo.gradle.internal.ApolloDownloadSchemaTask) { task ->
    description("Downloads Apollo Schema")
    group("Apollo")
    task.schemaRelativeToProject.set("src/main/java/com/project/backend/grqphql/schema.json")
    task.endpoint.set("http://your-project.com/graphql")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please describe what is the advantage of `schemaRelativeToProject` over `schemaFilePath` and `endpoint` over `endpointUrl`?